# Rotate map in print composer does not work with QuickMapServices plugin

Tags: qgis, print-composer, quickmapservices

I was very excited when I figured out that printing as pdf was actually possible with the plugin QuickMapServices after a lot of trying and pain with the old OpenLayers Plugin. However, if I try to rotate the map in the print composer I still get problems with the map not rendering correctly. It looks like the wrong axis is rotated. Is there a solution to this problem?

[image]

Comment: can you add a screen shot to show us what's happening?

Comment: I can confirm this is happening as well with QGIS 2.18.4. However, with the TileLayer Plugin, and using Digital Globe imagery (Digital Globe MapsAPI), I was able to rotate the layout in the print composer. Exporting to PDF only worked properly after setting the project CRS to UTM (which is the vector layer CRS). While using the Web Mercator CRS, the vector layer was shifting.

Comment: Possible answer [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230676/how-to-print-bing-aerial-maps-in-qgis#230677)