# How to print Bing Aerial maps in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, print-composer, bing-maps

I need to create a big number of maps in QGIS for a breeding bird monitoring scheme. The Bing Aerial maps would be perfect as underlying layer as they have sufficient resolution and very nice illumination.

When it comes to printing using OpenLayersPlugin and QuickMapService I get the well known problems. With QuickMapService I am almost there but I cannot rotate maps in the print composer (they get distorted). However, I need to rotate most maps to get the maximum extent of the areas on the print.

So my question: Is there any way to get Bing Maps Aerial into QGIS in a way that I can use it for printing? I have tried a lot already and other free satelite images do not have the same quality and resolution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the Sinica WMTS service, it has the Bing Aerial layer. It's url is:  http://gis.sinica.edu.tw/worldmap/wmts. Just use it as any other WMS or WMTS layer and it works just fine with rotated maps in Composer.

Comment: Great, that works perfectly and is everything I dreamed of! You made my day :-)

Comment: Thank you so much! Bing has higher quality resolution with more illumination of features that is VERY useful for geological prospecting within the Rockies. Your work made my work easier. Cheers.